# Scooping headers off of one Postman request and injecting them into others

Tags: rest, jwt, postman, bearer-token

My web service uses JWT-based authorization bearer token authentication:

1. HTTP clients send a valid POST to `/v1/auth/signIn` with a valid JSON request entity (includes username + password info)
2. If they authenticate successfully, that endpoint sends back an auth bearer token as an HTTP response header that (from curl) looks like:

Response from `curl`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Sep 2018 01:18:28 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
Authorization: Bearer <big_huge_string>
Content-Length: 0
```

3. Subsequent service calls to authenticated endpoints just need to include the token as an HTTP request header whose key/name is `Authorization` and whose value is "`Bearer <xyz>`" (where `<xyz>`) is the `<big_huge_string>` that came back on the sign in call above. Pretty basic standard JWT stuff.

I'm trying to write a Postman collection that starts with a "*Sign In Request*" that successfully signs in and gets a JWT token from the service, and then adds the appropriate HTTP request header in each subsequent call. Any ideas as to how I can:

1. Extract the `<big_huge_string>` off the HTTP response header that I'll get back from my Sign In Request?; and then
2. How to save that `<big_huge_string>` as a variable and inject that as an HTTP request header for all subsequent calls?

Thanks in advance!

---

#### Update

Tried the suggestion:

[image]

Getting closer, but `console.log(...)` isn't printing anything to Postman (or at least I don't know where to look for it). I should mention I'm *not* using the Chrome Application version of Postman, but the standalone app/executable (Version 6.1.4):

Any ideas how/where I can get `console.log(...)` working? I'm concerned about just changing the test to:

```
pm.test("Can Extract JWT", function() {
   var authHeader = pm.response.headers.toObject().Authorization;
   pm.expect(authHeader).to.not.be.equal(null);
   pm.globals.set('token', authHeader)
});
```

Without first seeing what that `authHeader` even is. Any ideas?!

Comment: Look for the icons in the bottom left corner of the app, it's the 3rd one. This will open a new console window.

Comment: Also, at this point, if it was correct you would see the value set as the global variable. You can check this in the 'environment quick view'. This is the eye icon in the top right. `to.not.be.null` would be the same check too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have that Token value you can reference it in each of the request headers using the `{{token}}` syntax. It's getting the sign in Auth header that's the harder part.

You could use `pm.response.headers` to get a list of the Headers and then extract out the value that you need.

This is returned as a list so maybe using something like Lodash or converting this to an object can help get the value you need. It would be something like `pm.response.headers.toObject().Authorization` - I haven't tried it so my syntax might be slightly wrong.

You can log the Headers out to the Postman console and narrow it down that way to - just wrap it in a `Console.log()` statement.

When you get that value, it's just a basic `pm.globals.set('token, pm.response.headers.toObject().Authorization)` to save this globally.

Comment: Thanks @Danny (+1) I **really** appreciate your answer here. I'm struggling with getting `console.log(...)` to work (of all things), please see my edits above. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Did that answer the original question?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be working, but without the ability to access wherever the console logs are going, I can't tell what `pm.response.headers.toObject().Authorization` evaluates to at runtime...

Comment: See my comment on the original question. "Head to View in the application menu, and click on “Show Postman Console” or use the keyboard shortcut (CMD/CTRL + ALT + C)."